# False positive in python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been writing a simple method to check if a web address has subdirectories and, if it does, separate them for me into a list. The code I wrote should ignore the last subdirectory the URL has (this was a mistake I realized after I noticed the loop was iterating about 4 times while checking a URL with a single subdirectory).

Here is the code:

```
import re

def check_web_address(web_address):
    #set the pattern, then check if it matches
    pattern = re.compile(r"[\w\-\.]*")
    pat_check = pattern.match(web_address)

    #if it does, separate the subdirs, assuming we checked for '/' earlier
    if pat_check:
        pattern_span = pat_check.span()
        web_add_no_subdir = web_address[pattern_span[0]:pattern_span[1]]
        raw_web_subs = web_address[pattern_span[1]:]
        web_subs = []

        """Check if there is an additional slash,
            then separate our subdir if the regex matches."""
        slash = "/"
        for slash in raw_web_subs[1:]:
            pat_span = pattern.match(raw_web_subs[1:]).span()
            real_end = pat_span[1]+1
            web_subs.append(raw_web_subs[:real_end])
            raw_web_subs = raw_web_subs[real_end:]

        separated = [
            web_add_no_subdir,
            web_subs
            ]
        return separated
    else:
        return None
```

This code actually returns a subdirectory, as my unittest says it ran the test successfully:

```
checked_add = wc.check_web_address("www.google.com/docs")
self.assertEqual(checked_add[0], 'www.google.com')
self.assertEqual(checked_add[1][0], '/docs')
```

So, I tested the following in the python console:

```
>>test = "/docs"
>>"/" in test[1:]
false
```

Also, if I ask python to print

```
raw_web_subs[1:]
```

Before the loop begins, I get the string "docs", without a forward slash.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the issue?   if `raw_web_subs = "/docs"` then the loop `for slash in raw_web_subs[1:]:` will iterate over `'d', 'o', 'c', 's'`, that is 4 times...

Comment: `slash = "/"; for slash in raw_web_subs[1:]:` I'm not entirely sure what you want this to do, but your console example suggests that you want to use the `for` statement as an `if` statement. That doesn't work that way.

Comment: Try `while slash in raw_web_subs[1:]:` instead.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing the whole pattern matching bits yourself, rather than using [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)?

Comment: As for why you only receive `'docs'` mutable objects in python indexes start at `0` therefore a `splice` of `test[1:]` will start at the 1 index and end at the end or -1. if you want to get the `'/'` you would have to grab the `test[0:]` however because a string is actually a mutable object in Python, there is no need to splice it. You could just say `if '/' in test:` and for determining if a string has a subdirectory you could just split the string at '/' using `test = some_string_url.split('/')` there is probably no need for `re` at all. Hope this explained it well.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen thanks for explaining what's going on. I'm a bit new to python and got a bit confused.

Comment: @Evert Thanks, I actually thought of this before checking my SO question.

Comment: @Blckknght I didn't realize that library existed. Python is a wonderful thing, I'll be sure to check it out.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I wanted to check if there were any subdirs after the first one, as this code was intended to be executed after checking if there was a subdir in the first place. Thanks for showing me how to accomplish my objective in such a simplified way.

Comment: This question falls under the "caused by a simple typographic error" category of "off topic" although I am very glad you got positive results from posting.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen is this something I can change by editing the question or is it something the mods should take care of? I can't seem to find a way to change the category.

Comment: No sorry I just meant that the original problem was caused by a typographic error so it is unlikely this will help future viewer that encounter the same issue, there isn't really anything you can do. (other then drastically change the question so it will be found, that would probably be worse) Don't worry about it just know it may be closed for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

As @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen explained, what is happening is that Python is iterating over each one of the characters, @Evert's suggested using a 'while' loop, which gives the result I was originally looking for.

I'll probably end up using [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) as @Blckknght suggested.

@TheLazyScripter Mentioned that what can also be done is to separate the string using test = some_string_url.split('/'). This is a much more elegant solution than what I had in mind.

Thank you everybody.

Comment: this is why when my condition for a while loop is `x in y` I use brackets: `while (slash in raw_web_subs[1:]):` is perfectly valid and clearly indicates the condition where `for (slash in raw_web_subs[1:]):` is both syntactically invalid and not at all what was intended.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen That's a good trick, I'll keep that in mind so I don't get the two mixed up again!